# AngularJS Directive Client does not run well

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to run AngularJS directive in my client project. I have no server.

When I use the `templateURL`, I get a few errors:

1. > Failed to load ... Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
2. > Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ./blPage.html (HTTP status: -1 )

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.9

Here is my angular code:

```
var app = angular.module("myModule" , []);

app.controller("myController" , ['$scope' , function($scope) {


}])
.directive('blPage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: './blPage.html'
  };
});
```

My directory tree is:
www(dir) -> index.html , blPage.html;
js(dir)  -> AppController.js

Comment: post the relevant code

Comment: I added my angular code

Comment: Its because when using templateURL you need to serve you application from server. Angualr app with routes and templatesUrl dont work with file protocal.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the url provided is not valid.

> Solution 1

1. Check the url the apllication searches for `blPage.html`
2. Compare if the path is valid
3. Get the correct path and add that it `templateUrl:` option

> Solution 2

1. Insted of adding `teplateUrl:'blPage.html'` use `template:` option
2. Copy the html code written in `blPage.html` and add that to template value. Example: `template:<div>{{value}}</div>`